# doNothing non void method with params in other class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public class aClass {
   public String meth1() {
      bClass b = new bClass();
      b.meth2();// I don't want to call this method
      //buss logic
   }
}

public class bClass {
   public String meth2() {
      // some logic
   } 
}
```

Currently I am creating a JUnit test case for the meth1 in `aClass`. However, I don't want to call the `meth2` in `bClass`, just execute the busslogic in `aClass`. The Classes `aClass` and `bClass` are fixed - I cannot change their code.

I tried many things like `@InjectMocks` and `doNothing` using Mockito and PowerMock, but `meth2` always gets called when I am calling `meth1` in `aClass`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Since you can't inject BClass into AClass, you'll need to use something more powerful than Mockito, that is able to mock constructors. PowerMockito can do that, AFAIK.

Comment: You cannot mock a local variable. Either create an instance member or pass it to the method.

Answer (score 0):

PowerMock to the rescue:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ aClass.class })
public class TestPowerMock {

    @Test
    public void shouldBlaBla() throws Exception {
        // you can do whatever you want on bMock, because it's a mock
        bClass bMock = PowerMockito.mock(bClass.class);
        // when aClass instantiates bClass, the mock will be returned
        PowerMockito.whenNew(bClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(bMock);
        // your test
        aClass a = new aClass();
        a.meth1();
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects)